# MongoDB migrate Array to Dictionary

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongo-shell

I have an array inside my document that has no key right now. I want to add keys to the array.

So what I have is:

`{
  "arrayToConvert":[43.323,32.1223]
}`

What I want to get as a result is:

`{
  "arrayToConvert":{"a":43.323,"b":32.1223}
}`

Thanks for some help :)

Comment: You'll need to write a bit of code to loop through all docs and convert the array to your new structure. What have you tried, and what didn't work?

Comment: I know the forEach but I don't know how to reference the first and the second array value in the code.. There is $ for the first match but I just always need 1. and 2. entry of the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with `forEach`:

```
db.collection.find().snapshot().forEach( function(document) {
  db.collection.update(document, { $set: { arrayToConvert: { a: document.arrayToConvert[0], b: document.arrayToConvert[1] } } });
});
```